# hover doesn't work with mouseleave

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/yZSEA/

```
$("p").hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this).find('span');
    $this.show();
}, function() {
    $this.hide();
});
```

I don't want to use mouseenter and mouseleave to avoid ugly code, the idea above is given in jquery documentation, logically it's fine but the mouseleave part didn't work

Comment: `$this` isn't set in the second function - try `$(this).hide()`

Comment: That is because in the `mouseleave` `$this` is not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've haven't defined `$this` in your mouseleave function and your code is throwing:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $this is not defined

Simply repeat your `var $this` declaration in the mouseleave function:

```
$("p").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this).find('span');
    $this.show();
}, function(){
    var $this = $(this).find('span');
    $this.hide();
});
```

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/yZSEA/2/).

Comment: can var $this of 1st function be accessed in 2nd?

Comment: `$this` is local to each function. This means the second function cannot access it. You don't actually need to declare a variable in your example, however, you can simply just call `$(this).find('span').show()` and `$(this).find('span').hide()`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `$this` in the context of the mouseleave handler is `undefined`, you should also define the variable in that handler.

You can also use `on` and `toggle` methods(*if it's not ugly*):

```
$("p").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('span', this).toggle(e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is not declared in your mouseout scope. Just do the `.find` call again in your mouse out handler:

```
$("p").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('span').show();
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('span').hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

add `var $this = $(this).find('span');` again when mouseleave happen

```
$("p").hover(function(){
var $this = $(this).find('span');
$this.show();
    }, function(){
        var $this = $(this).find('span');
        $this.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this).find('span');
    $this.show();
        }, function(){
            var $this = $(this).find('span');
    $this.hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

add $this to your leave function also:

```
$("p").hover(function(){
        var $this = $(this).find('span');
        $this.show();
    }, function(){
           var $this = $(this).find('span');
           $this.hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('p').hover(function() {
       $(this).find('span').show();

             },function() {

    $(this).find('span').hide();
   });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yZSEA/3/)